# Suitescript - Is it possible to set/default the Declared Value to true on Item Fulfillment Packages?

Tags: package, netsuite, suitescript

I am not able to get any values or set any values on the Packages tab. I am looking to default the Declared Value checkbox to 'T' on pageinit so that it is always checked. In the console I receive null for nlapiGetFieldValue('useinsuredvalueups'), both when checked and not checked. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're going to need to use nlapiGetLineItemCount('packages')
Then loop through each line item and then use nlapiSetLineItemValue('packages', 'yourField', 'T', x) where x is your line item you're looping through.

Comment: I am trying to do this when the page loads, so at this point there will not be any packages. When I try nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('packages', 'useinsuredvalueups', 'T'), this does not work. I also try nlapiSelectNewLineItem('packages') before and that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the package lines until you have marked the Item Fullfillment as shipped. So you'll want to trap pageIntit, fieldChanged, postSourcing and lineInit events. Also since the package list is still not supported you should be aware that client side the list would be accessed as

```
nlapiGetLineItemCount('package')
```

I think that may be fixed server side now as well so that testing for packageups, packagenonups, packagefedex is no longer necessary..

Comment: Confused. So would this be a client or server side script? What would it look and what type of event would it need to be triggered on? I don't know what you mean by trap all of those types.

Comment: your original message discussed pageInit. That is a client script type. The types I mentioned are also client script event types.

Comment: Yes, but I try this in a client on pageinit and it does not work. I try in the console and I get "-1" for packages (most likely because of what you said - I cannot get package lines until marked as shipped). So is there any way I can default the Declared Value to be "T" when the page loads? If so, how?

Comment: `nlapiGetLineItemCount('package')` will give 1 when the item fulfillment is first set to Packed or Shipped. `nlapiGetLineItemCount('packages')` will always return -1 because packages is not the list name.

Comment: My bad - typo - I use nlapiGetLineItemCount('package') and I get -1. So just clearing up there is NO way to default this Declared Value field to 'T' when the page loads on a new fulfillment?

Comment: No because your new fulfillments load in Picked status by default and there are no packages then. If you set the fulfillment to Packed or Shipped then the package list becomes available. So use a fieldChanged, postSourcing or lineInit client function to set it.